# How to insert data into more than one table using sp in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server

How do I `insert` data into several tables each with different types and number of parameters. e.g

**Table1**

```
Code Type
'A'   X
```

**Table 2**

```
Code Type Status Dasl
```

Here the number of parameters are different.

In this case how to `insert` the data into tables using a common `stored procedure`.

Comment: you will required 2 `insert` statement. One for each table. Create stored procedure for each of the table. Don't try to make it common. Unless the 2 tables are related with FK, in this case, you do it in a single stored procedure within one transaction

Comment: I agree - don't try and make a "kitchen sink" stored procedure that can insert into any table. This is overly complicated and a database anti-pattern. What is your objective? Limit database access through a stored proc?

Comment: What is your end goal? Why do you need to create the `Stored Procedure` in the first place?

Comment: @Birel my requirement is to save it through stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Create sample stored procedure to get an idea how to save data into records.
Create Table Type like below to insert multiple records in to your database

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[tbl_Table2] AS TABLE(
    [Code] [char](2) NULL,
    [Type] [char](2) NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [Dasl] [varchar](5) NULL
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Usp_DataInsert] 
(
@Code  CHAR(2),
@Type CHAR(2),
@tbl_Table2 AS tbl_Table2 READONLY
)
AS 
BEGIN TRY 

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tbl_Table2)
    BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO Table2
    (
     Code
    ,[Type]
    ,[Status]
    ,Dasl
    )
    SELECT Code
          ,[Type]
          ,[Status]
            ,Dasl 
    FROM @tbl_Table2
    END
    INSERT INTO Table1
    (
    Code,
    [Type]
    )
    SELECT @Code,@Type

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
        DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

        SELECT 
            @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
            @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
            @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
                   @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
                   @ErrorState -- State.
               );
END CATCH;
```

Insert data into table through stored procedure

```
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @Code char(2)='Z'
DECLARE @Type char(2)=33
DECLARE @tbl_Table2 tbl_Table2

INSERT INTO @tbl_Table2
SELECT 'A','X','A','AB' UNION ALL
SELECT 'A','X','A','AB' UNION ALL
SELECT 'A','X','A','AB' UNION ALL
SELECT 'A','X','A','AB' 

EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[Usp_DataInsert] 
   @Code
  ,@Type
  ,@tbl_Table2
GO
```

Comment: Hi,
This is good meeting the requirement. But my front end screen is Excel VBA. So here I cant use table valued parameters. What I am done is created a master sp from that i called different stored procedures each table wise. Is this holds good?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use different stored procedures to insert with multiple tables with different parameters, You can use transaction from front end also